# How to archive a repository on GitHub

Tags: github, repository

Instead of closing/deleting I want to archive one of my git repositories on GitHub. I have seen on multiple projects a yellow banner with the message "This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only." but I can't find out how to achieve this.

Examples:
https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew 
https://github.com/semantic-release/commit-analyzer-v2

[image: Screenshot: Yellow archived banner on GitHub]




Does anyone know how to do this or is it just possible for repositories with a big community?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s within the generic `Settings` of your repository. In there you’ll find the `Danger Zone` at the very bottom of the website. There is a new button called `Archive this repository`.

[image: Danger Zone]

Answer (score 1):

You can also archive your GitHub repository from command-line, without having to search for an option in the GitHub Web UI.

From [GitHub CLI 2.1.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.1.0), you now (Oct. 2021) have the command-line option [`gh archive`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_archive):

```
gh repo archive <repository>
```

This fixes [issue 1398](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1398) ("archive command for repositories"), through [PR 4410](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/4410) ("`gh repo archive`"), and [commit ec55482](https://github.com/cli/cli/commit/ec554822b81d3f26095ef6b4eff10ce7cc2f8174).

Your repository will be marked "archived".

---

Note:

> ### [Unarchive a repository via the REST API](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-13-unarchive-a-repository-via-the-rest-api) (Dec. 2022)
>
> You can now unarchive a repository via the REST API.
> Previously, unarchiving was only available via the GraphQL API or the UI.
>
> [Learn more about updating repositories via the REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-repository)

```bash
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  --method PATCH \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO \
  -F archived=false
```

With:

> ### `archived`: `boolean`
>
> Whether to archive this repository.
> **`false` will unarchive a previously archived repository**.
>
> Default: `false`

Comment: Oct. 2022: see also "[Keep your project tidy with auto-archive](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-18-the-new-github-issues-october-18th-update/#%F0%9F%A7%B9-keep-your-project-tidy-with-auto-archive)".

Answer (score 0):

1. goto `GitHub account`
2. select `setting`(upper right)
3. goto down the page(in `Danger Zone`)
4. select `Unarchive this repository`
5. `Type the message what is written in the upper of the message box`
6. Press `I understand the consequence, unarchive the repository`
7. Now your problem is solved
8. And again upload your project using git bash

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, which was how to archive a repository. But I'm glad to know that un-archiving is possible as well! Before reading your answer, I assumed archiving was irreversible, but now I know better. :)