# How can I batch archive all GitHub repositories in my account?

Tags: github, github-api

How do I batch archive my repositories? I'd preferably want to be able to sort through them and figure out a way to not archive my active repositories.

I have hundreds of old GitHub repositories in my account since before the GitHub notifications feature, and now I get vulnerability notifications for all of them. Here's what my notifications look, for projects that were last used maybe 6 years ago:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the GitHub API along with two tools to achieve this. I'll be using:

- [Hub](https://hub.github.com/), but you can make direct API calls
- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), but you can use any JSON parser

Here's how:

1. Fetch a list of all the GitHub repositories in our account, and saving them in a file:

   `hub api --paginate users/amingilani/repos | jq -r '.[]."full_name"' > repos_names.txt`
2. Go through that file manually, remove any repositories you **don't** want to archive
3. Archive all the repositories in the file:

   `cat repos_names.txt | xargs -I {} -n 1 hub api -X PATCH -F archived=true /repos/{}`

Comment: I used the official GitHub CLI, `gh`. These commands worked identically, just swap out `hub` for `gh`. I checked to see if the list repos API request can filter out archived repos. Looks like no, but the `jq` command can probably filter out those results.

Comment: @EricHu when I tried it with `gh` I was having trouble with pagination—I had a lot of repositories. It's possible it may work now.

Answer (score 5):

Note: since 2020:

- [`gh repo list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_list) has been released (with [`gh` 1.7.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.7.0) in [commit 00cb921](https://github.com/cli/cli/commit/00cb921cd5882a963932b655fb6226da26ef6550), Q1 2021): it does take pagination in account, as it is similar to an alias like:

```sh
set -e

repos() {
  local owner="${1?}"
  shift 1
  gh api graphql --paginate -f owner="$owner" "$@" -f query='
    query($owner: String!, $per_page: Int = 100, $endCursor: String) {
      repositoryOwner(login: $owner) {
        repositories(first: $per_page, after: $endCursor, ownerAffiliations: OWNER) {
          nodes {
            nameWithOwner
            description
            primaryLanguage { name }
            isFork
            pushedAt
          }
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ' | jq -r '.data.repositoryOwner.repositories.nodes[] | [.nameWithOwner,.pushedAt,.description,.primaryLanguage.name,.isFork] | @tsv' | sort
}

repos "$@"
```

- `gh repo list --no-archived` can limit the list to your not-yet-archived repositories
- [`gh repo archive`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69939069/6309) can then, for each element of that list, archive the GitHub repository.

---

[wolfram77](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413259/wolfram77) also proposes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170138/how-can-i-batch-archive-all-github-repositories-in-my-account/69939165?noredirect=1#comment126618339_69939165):

```
gh repo list <org> | awk '{NF=1}1' | \
  while read in; do gh repo archive -y "$in"; done
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is a one-liner for that `gh repo list <org> | awk '{NF=1}1' | while read in; do gh repo archive -y "$in"; done`.

Comment: @wolfram77 Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

Using only gh.

```
gh repo list --no-archived --limit 144 --visibility public --source --json nameWithOwner --jq ".[].nameWithOwner" > repos_names.txt
```

Set `--limit` to the number of repositories you have.
Use vim to delete line which you don't want to archive by pressing `dd` on the line:

```
vim repos_names.txt
```

Run the the following command to arrive them

```
cat repos_names.txt | while read in; do gh repo archive -y "$in"; done
```

Clear after:

```
rm repos_names.txt
```